# configuring Spring web flow demo app to use JBoss 7 managed datasource

Tags: spring, jboss, jboss7.x, spring-webflow

I have a container managed datasource("myDataSource") configured in a Jboss 7 server.  The datasource appears to be deployed correctly (I checked it from the admin console).
I built and deployed the Spring sample webflow-primefaces-showcase application to jboss,  the demo deployed and worked correctly.
I want to use the jboss datasource with the demo, but I can't get it to work.  At this point I don't have any backing code that will access the database, I just want to get the datasource configured correctly.

I added a dependency to the pom.xml for the oracle driver

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
<version>11.1.0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I Created META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="myDataSource-emf" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/myDataSource</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/> 
         <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="schemaUserName"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
```

added this to web.xml:

```
 <persistence-unit-ref>
  <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence/myDataSource-emf</persistence-unit-ref-name>
  <persistence-unit-name>myDataSource-emf</persistence-unit-name>
 </persistence-unit-ref>
```

When I deploy now I get:

```
    "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => 
    "jboss.persistenceunit.\"webflow-primefaces-showcase-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war#myDataSource-emf\
    "jboss.naming.context.java.myDataSourceMissing
[jboss.persistenceunit.\"webflow-primefaces-showcase-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war#myDataSource-emf\
    "jboss.naming.context.java.myDataSource]"]}
```

Somewhere I have to add the jndi reference:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManager" jndi-name="java:comp/env/persistence/myDataSource-emf" 
            expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManager"/>
```

But I'm not sure where.  Do I need to create an ApplicationContext.xml?  Can I put it in the rootContext.xml?

How do I make these two play nice together?

my configuration:

- JBoss 7.1
- Spring 3.1.2
- Spring Web Flow 2.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in persistence.xml
I changed this line:

```
<jta-data-source>java:/myDataSource</jta-data-source>
```

to:

```
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/myDataSource</jta-data-source>
```

I put the jndi lookup in the servlet-context.xml:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="java:comp/env/persistence/myDataSource-emf" 
            expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory"/>
```

And edited the schema references to add the jndi tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">
```